# Script launched from PHP does not work correctly, but it does from command line

Tags: php, shell, sh

I create and run a shell script from a php script. The script has an `if`. Commands on `then` don't run when they should, but instead commands in `else` run when they shouldn't. When I run the same script from the command line, it works as expected.

**php file:**

```
<?php
 .....
$msg = "#! /bin/sh\n\n";
file_put_contents($scriptfile, $msg, LOCK_EX);
$cmd = "/usr/bin/pdftohtml -noframes -q -p -s -i $renfilenc\n";
file_put_contents($scriptfile, $cmd, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
$noExtfile = preg_replace('"\.(pdf|PDF)$"', '', $renfilenc);
$cmd = "if [[ \$(grep -c -o \"</p>\" $noExtfile.html) -le 5 ]];
then
    /usr/bin/gs -dNOPAUSE -q -r500 -sDEVICE=tiffg4 -dBATCH -sOutputFile=$noExtfile.tiff $renfilenc
    /usr/bin/tesseract $noExtfile.tiff $noExtfile -c tessedit_create_hocr=1 -c hocr_font_info=1
else
    /usr/bin/unoconv -f docx $noExtfile.html
    /usr/bin/curl -i -F \"Profile=jsi\" -F \"Output=url\" -F \"Language=en\" -F \"infile=@$noExtfile.docx\" -F \"submit=Submit\" http://nl.ijs.si/tei/cgi/convert.pl > TEIconvert.log
    grep -E -o \"http://.*\" TEIconvert.log > wgetline.log
    sed -r \"s/^(.*).$/wget \\1\/tei.xml -O $noExtfile.xml/g\" wgetline.log > wgetTEIfile.sh
    /bin/sh  wgetTEIfile.sh
fi";
file_put_contents($scriptfile, $cmd, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
$cmd = "/bin/sh  $scriptfile > /dev/null 2>&1 &";
shell_exec($cmd);
.....
?>
```

**created script file:**

```
#! /bin/sh

/usr/bin/pdftohtml -noframes -q -p -s -i USNews_Bostonian_image.pdf
if [[ $(grep -c -o "</p>" USNews_Bostonian_image.html) -le 5 ]];
then
   /usr/bin/gs -dNOPAUSE -q -r500 -sDEVICE=tiffg4 -dBATCH -sOutputFile=USNews_Bostonian_image.tiff USNews_Bostonian_image.pdf
   /usr/bin/tesseract USNews_Bostonian_image.tiff USNews_Bostonian_image -c tessedit_create_hocr=1 -c hocr_font_info=1
else
   /usr/bin/unoconv -f docx USNews_Bostonian_image.html
   /usr/bin/curl -i -F "Profile=jsi" -F "Output=url" -F "Language=en" -F "infile=@USNews_Bostonian_image.docx" -F "submit=Submit" http://nl.ijs.si/tei/cgi/convert.pl > TEIconvert.log
   grep -E -o "http://.*" TEIconvert.log > wgetline.log
   sed -r "s/^(.*).$/wget \1\/tei.xml -O USNews_Bostonian_image.xml/g" wgetline.log > wgetTEIfile.sh
   /bin/sh  wgetTEIfile.sh
fi
```

In this case the commands on `then` should run, not the ones on `else`.
Any ideas if something is wrong or missing?

Comment: I suspect your issue may have to do with relative file paths.  Your if condition does not refer to the file path.

Comment: all files are at the same directory, php file, script file and uploaded file, aswell as the generated ones

Comment: but when the php code is executed, "it" is not necessarily "in" that directory.  to be sure, try adding the path to your file and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: It didn't help, but I added an output to a log file and I get: script.sh: `4: script.sh: [[: not found` line 4 is `if [[ $(grep -c -o "</p>" /srv/web/llocs/proves/USNews_Bostonian_image.html) -le 5 ]];`

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/374406/why-do-i-get-not-found-when-running-a-script

So in my php I changed:

```
$msg = "#! /bin/sh\n\n";
```

and

```
$cmd = "/bin/sh  $scriptfile > /dev/null 2>&1 &";
```

to

```
$msg = "#!/bin/bash \n\n";
```

and

```
$cmd = "/bin/bash  $scriptfile > /dev/null 2>&1 &";
```

respectively